# how many numbers of irrationality measure $x$

Tags: irrational-numbers

Does there exist $x>2$ such that uncountably many reals have irrationality measure x? Must there exist at least one number of irrationality measure $x$?

[related question on sets of constant irrationality measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10761/15624)

Comment: the question you linked contains an answer: by Jarnik-Besikovitch theorem, the set of real numbers of any given irrationality measure has non-zero Haussdorff dimension, so it is uncountable (hence non-empty)